# How to change uploaded file name in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento, file-upload

I am using system.xml configuration to upload a file via backend. It works perfectly.

But I need to change the uploaded image's name to the current `store id`. How Can I? Now it is uploaded with its original name.

My `system.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <tabs>
    <restaurant translate="label" module="restaurant">
        <label>Upload Logo</label>
        <sort_order>999999</sort_order>
    </restaurant>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
    <restaurant_options translate="label">
      <label>Upload Logo</label>
      <tab>general</tab>
      <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
      <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
       <groups>
            <SAMPLE translate="label">
              <label>Upload Your Store's Logo</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>100</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
              <fields>
                    <ENABLED translate="label comment">
                        <label>Logo</label>
                        <comment>file types: jpeg, gif, png.</comment>
                        <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                        <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
                        <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">theme</upload_dir>
                        <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">theme</base_url>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </ENABLED>
            </fields>
            </SAMPLE>
      </groups>
    </restaurant_options>
  </sections>
</config>
```

Please If any know a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know.
First insert record into database and get inserted id by using

$uniqID = mysql_insert_id();

then

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $path_to_upload . $uniqID);

Beware: Don't forget to get file extension.